# Как узнать, загрузились ли картинки в блоке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блоке, в котором находятся картинки. После загрузки всех картинок в блоке нужно выполнить функцию. Как узнать, что все картинки в блоке загружены?

Comment: подписаться на событие `onload` у картинок

Comment: на **jq**   `$('.div img').load(function() { // загрузились });`

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, в данном случае может вызываться [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) а не навешиватель события

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще есть несколько вариантов:

1) против велосипедистов есть плагин:
https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

2) или может как-нибудь так?

```
var def = [];

$promise =  $('img').on('load', function() {
    this.def.resolve();
})
.attr("src", function() {
    this.def = $.Deferred();
    def.push(this.def);

    return this.src;
}).promise().done(function() {
    $.when.apply($, def).done(function( ajaxResult ){
        console.log('images is load');
    });
});
```

3) а чтобы не изменять атрибут `src`, может быть добавить на `onload` изображения функцию?

```
<img onload="this.setAttribute('loaded', 'loaded')">

$('img:not([loaded=loaded])')...
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно подписаться на событие `onload` у всех картинок, поднимать счетчик после загрузки каждой картинки и вызывать функцию, когда все загружены.

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");
bindImagesOnload(block, function() {
    console.log("Все картинки загружены!");
});
function bindImagesOnload(node, fn) {
    var imgs = node.getElementsByTagName("img"),
        length = imgs.length;
    var counter = 0;
    var onload = function() {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= length)
            fn();
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        imgs[i].onload = onload;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
    <img src="//www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/thanksgiving-2015-6462359094689792-hp.jpg">
    <img src="//www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <img src="//www.google.cn/landing/cnexp/google-search.png">
</div>
```

Comment: это только если на момент вызова `bindImagesOnload` все теги `img` уже есть

Comment: @Grundy Да, и ещё только тогда, когда загруженных картинок нету (а то считает не правильно).

Comment: а он разве не должен, в случае если `onload` уже прошел - просто сразу функцию обработчика вызвать?

Comment: @Grundy А как узнать, прошел ли `onload` уже?

Comment: @PeterOlson в общем, всё равно проще всего устанавливать `src` картинок только после добавления обработчика события `load`.

Comment: вот в принципе похожие вопросы: [один](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript), [второй](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery). И как я понимаю меня не правильно поняли: я думал такое поведение по дефолту должно было быть:)

Comment: @Grundy да какое уж тут "по дефолту"... Лично у меня, например, [такой пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kw3x3ko5/) с `setTimeout` превращает всё в тыкву.

Comment: @Regent, почему в тыкву? Вроде же отрабатывает все?

Comment: @Grundy у меня (в Opera 33) в консоли сообщение _""Все картинки загружены!"_ не появляется, только _"Timed out"_.

Comment: @Regent, а в хроме последнем нормально

Comment: @Grundy в _Chrome 46.0_ у меня аналогичная ситуация: только _"Timed out"_. Я это всё к чему веду-то: добавлять обработчик `load` после установки `src` - дело ненадёжное.